# Python: how to build a text file for loading data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-files, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

**I'm new to Python, and I am following this guide to implement a linear regression**
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jdwittenauer/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/ml/ML-Exercise1.ipynb

**Basically I am on the step where I need to build a data set to import it into Python**

[image]

**I have created a text file with two columns, each data is separated by a tab**

[image]

**However, this is what I get**

[image]

**I looked around online and it seems that the tab is the delimiter. What am I doing wrong? How can I build this text file?**

Comment: Try adding the parameter `delimiter='\t'` to `read_csv()`. This will then spot your tabs. Normally CSV files use commas to separate each value (thus the name)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code - see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) meta post on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using the official documentation instead of "looking around online" - if you check the [pandas read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation, it lists (at the very top) the default values of each argument. The default value of the sep (separator) argument is ", ". So just change your call to `pd.read_csv()` to add `sep='\t'`.

Answer (score 1):

use ',' instead of 'tab' as a delimiter in your textfile ex1data.txt, as pandas default delimiter is ','.

Here is an explanation from pandas official documentation for delimiter :

> sep : str, default ‘,’ 
>   Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine
>   cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing
>   engine can, meaning the latter will be used automatically. In
>   addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+'
>   will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use
>   of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to
>   ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'